# How to execute in C++ a task in the Windows main loop

Tags: c++, windows

Is there a way to schedule a task to be executed in the Windows main loop. I don't want to create a Windows and send an event to it.

With libdispatch I can do it with:

```
dispatch_async_f(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...)
```

Or is there a thread in the Windows Thread Pool associated with the program's main loop?

Background:
Currently I am in the process of developing a CSP (Communicating Sequential Processing) library and most of the time tasks can be executed by the Thread Pool. But sometimes there is the need that a task is executed in the main loop. I have already a solution, if the application under Windows is a Qt application. But for non Qt applications under Windows I would like to have a solution as well.

Comment: I'm no Windows expert, but aren't all threads in GUI mode applications bound to a window? I thought that this was how they differed from console mode applications. So surely you have a window?

Comment: Really unclear what you're asking. Do you want to hook into the GetMessage loop? Windows apps are by default single-threaded and event-based.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Why can't you create a new thread using CreateThread() call and do your "task" in it?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows each message loop is associated with a single thread. You can have more than one message loop per application if this is what you ask.